# What is a "shoulder lock" in Judo terminology?

Tags: judo, terminology, joint-lock, anatomy

In a judo context, "elbow-lock" has a [broader definition](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9352/why-is-ude-garami-legal-if-it-is-effectively-a-shoulder-lock) than in other martial arts, referring to both armbars and bent-arm rotational locks (since both manipulate the elbow joint for effect, regardless of the point of pain).<sup>[1](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9391/are-hammerlocks-te-gatame-legal-in-judo-competition) [2](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9414/are-omoplatas-legal-in-judo/9415)</sup>

Given this, what *does* a shoulder lock refer to in judo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Judo texts which use "elbow lock" to refer to bent-arm locks, the term "shoulder lock" appears in two contexts:

- *kata-gatame* ("shoulder hold", *osaekomi-waza*)<sup>1 2 3</sup>
- *kata-ha-jime* ("single wing choke", *shime-waza*)<sup>4</sup>

Here, "lock" appears to be a translation of "katame" - i.e. while these "lock" the shoulder in place, they are not *kansetsu-waza* since they do not cause pain to the arm by stretching, bending, or twisting it (i.e. they are *katame* but not *ude-hishigi*). As such they are legal, as incorporated in the above techniques.

---

**Notes:**

<sup>**1.** [*My Method of Judo*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=a_G1AAAAIAAJ&q=%22shoulder+lock%22), Mikinosuke Kawaishi (1955)</sup>
<sup>**2.** [*Jūdō*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=qBcLAAAAIAAJ&q=%22shoulder+lock%22), Sakujirō Yokoyama, ‎Eisuké Ōshima (1915)</sup>
<sup>**3.** [*Judo for Young Men*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=DhF4prvzzNAC&dq=%22shoulder+lock%22), Tadao Ōtaki, Donn F. Draeger (1965)</sup>
<sup>**4.** [*Higher Judo - Groundwork*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=G6gif_EMVNEC) (p.173) (1952)</sup>

> <sup>Figs. **193** and **194** show a strangle-hold combined with a shoulder-lock.</sup>
> [image]