# Are Omoplatas legal in judo?

Tags: judo, brazilian-jiu-jitsu, sport, anatomy, joint-lock

Are omoplatas legal in judo? Though they cause pain to the shoulder joint, they "lock" the elbow joint (in a bent position) to achieve this (as in [*ude-garami*](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9352/why-is-ude-garami-legal-if-it-is-effectively-a-shoulder-lock) and [*te-gatame*](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9391/are-hammerlocks-te-gatame-legal-in-judo-competition)).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, omoplatas are considered a variant of *ashi-gatame* or *hiza-gatame*.<sup>1 3</sup> The IJF Referee Commission has confirmed their legality on multiple occasions,<sup>1 2</sup> both as a submission, and as a  turnover:

> [image]
>
> **Lascau:** Osaekomi.
>
> **Demonstrator:** *uke taps, tori points at armlock*
>
> **Lascau:** Ippon. Ippon.
>
> **Demonstrator:** [With this movement,] making the kansetsu-waza? [It's ok?]
>
> **Lascau:** Ippon. No problem. Ashi-gatame. Ashi-gatame, combination with rolling, and then osaekomi or ashi-/hiza-gatame, depending how is the hand.

They are occasionally seen in competition, and are the signature techniques of some high level judoka (e.g. Huizinga, Munkhbat):

| Submission (*ashi-/hiza-gatame*)⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ | "Huizinga roll"⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ |
| --- | --- |
| • [Düsseldorf Grand Prix 2020 | 73kg | An vs Sterpu](https://youtu.be/xkVhWiAWkAs?t=319) • [Osaka Grand Slam 2019 | 57kg | Klimkait vs Tamaoki](https://youtu.be/j61-3Pad-ao&t=351) • [Antalya Grand Prix 2017 | 52kg | Azizova vs Tas](https://www.ijf.org/judoka/19347/videos?currentContestCodeLong=gp_tur2017_w_0052_0017) • [Tokyo Grand Slam 2015 | 60kg | Aoki vs Chammartin](https://www.ijf.org/judoka/28720/videos?currentContestCodeLong=gs_jpn2015_m_0060_0062) • [Hohhot Grand Prix 2017 | 48kg | Munkhbat vs Wang](https://www.ijf.org/judoka/209/videos?currentContestCodeLong=gp_chn2017_w_0052_0033) • [Baku Grand Slam 2014 | 48kg | Munkhbat vs Rosseneu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uZxY8xXeuJM&t=50) • [Paris Grand Slam 2018 | 48kg | Munkhbat vs Guan](https://www.ijf.org/judoka/209/videos?currentContestCodeLong=gs_fra2018_w_0048_0017) • [Paris Grand Slam 2017 | 48kg | Munkhbat vs Mosdier](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fh0ZcFvH4-0) • [Paris Grand Slam 2016 | 48kg | Munkhbat vs Nikolic](https://www.ijf.org/judoka/209/videos?currentContestCodeLong=gs_fra2016_w_0048_0025) • [Tashkent Grand Prix 2017 | 48kg | Munkhbat vs Pavlenko](https://www.ijf.org/judoka/209/videos?currentContestCodeLong=gp_uzb2017_w_0048_0009) • [World Masters Rabat 2015 | 48kg | Munkhbat vs Pareto](https://www.judoinside.com/judovideo/25756/Urantsetseg_MUNKHBAT_MGL_Paula_PARETO_ARG_IJF_World_Masters_Rabat_2015) • [World Championships Baku 2018 | 48kg | Munkhbat vs Costa](https://www.ijf.org/judoka/209/videos?currentContestCodeLong=wc_sen2018_w_0048_0057) • [World Championships Baku 2018 | 100kg+ | Durlenbayar vs Pineda](https://www.judoinside.com/judovideo/67448/Duurenbayar_ULZIIBAYAR_MGL_Pedro_PINEDA_VEN_O100_World_Championships_Baku_2018) • [World Championships Seoul 1985 | 100kg | Saito vs. Cohen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=87thuSVewPw&t=315) | • [2007 Tournois de Paris | 90kg | Huizinga vs Dafreville](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gCZ0Be0e4v4) • [2010 World Cup Lisbon | 81kg | Canto vs Stevens](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IGi8zG0p2QQ) • [Grand Prix Agadir 2018 | 57kg | Harachi vs Iraoui](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QD_RZkMMSzQ) • [Havana Grand Prix 2016 | 57kg | Harachi vs David](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1jWzBVyOdk4) • [Grand Prix Budapest 2016 | 60kg | Aoki vs Bestaev](https://www.judoinside.com/judovideo/47306/Otar_BESTAEV_KGZ_Dai_AOKI_JPN_U60_Final_Grand_Prix_Budapest_2016) • [World Championships Budapest 2017 | 73kg | Ungvári vs Ruiz](https://www.judoinside.com/judovideo/55085/Jeffrey_RUIZ_PUR_Miklos_UNGVARI_HUN_U73_World_Championships_Budapest_2017) |

---

<sup>1. [IJF Refereeing & Coaching Seminar  2016: Day 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kLy8ggzTWpw&t=25200) (6:59:55)</sup>
<sup>2. [IJF Refereeing & Coaching Seminar  2018: Day 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JVGZTua49Xs&t=10760) (2:59:20)</sup>
<sup>3. [*Kodokan Katame-Waza: Various Techniques and their Names*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VHJ1M3htDnM&t=850) (1994)</sup>

Comment: [Giles Antalya GS 2022](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7cpM2JeD5M&t=628s)